# Getting Angular Material Typography Styles

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-material

How does one get the typography level styles inside a custom component in Angular Material v16?

We used to be able to write this in the component.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
$config: mat-typography-config();
.unicorn-title {
  @include mat-typography-level-to-styles($config, title);
}
```

What is the current equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

I typically create a configuration file, such as typography.scss, to define all typography settings for Angular Material.

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

$erp-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
    $font-family: 'Montserrat, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    $headline-1: mat.define-typography-level(2.4rem, 2.8rem, 400, 'Oswald, Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif'),
    $headline-2: mat.define-typography-level(2rem, 2.4rem, 400, 'Oswald, Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif'),
    $headline-3: mat.define-typography-level(1.6rem, 2rem, 700),
    $headline-4: mat.define-typography-level(1.6rem, 2rem, 400),
    $headline-5: mat.define-typography-level(2.4rem, 2.8rem, 400, 'Oswald, Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif'),
    $headline-6: mat.define-typography-level(2rem, 2.4rem, 400, 'Oswald, Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif'),
    $subtitle-1: mat.define-typography-level(1.6rem, 2rem, 700),
    $subtitle-2: mat.define-typography-level(1.6rem, 2rem, 400),
    $body-1: mat.define-typography-level(1.6rem, 2rem, 400),
    $body-2: mat.define-typography-level(1.6rem, 2rem, 400),
    $caption: mat.define-typography-level(1.2rem, 2rem, 400),
    $button: mat.define-typography-level(1.4rem, 1.4rem, 500),
    $overline: mat.define-typography-level(1.4rem, 1.4rem, 500),
);
```

Each parameter, like headline-1, subtitle-1, etc., is detailed in the Material Documentation. [Typography levels](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography)

Finally, you need to include the entire typography configuration in your custom theme or main SCSS file:

```
@use './theming/typography' as typo;
@include mat.all-component-typographies(typo.$typography);
```

I hope this helps or points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created your global typography configuration and initialised it using your theme you can then access properties from it in other components stylesheets using the following:

```css
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$config: mat.define-typography-config();

.some-class-name {
  @include mat.line-height($config, 'body-1');
}
```

This example sets the line height of `some-class-name` to the line height of `body-1` in your typography config.